# convert and rotate video from MOV (iphone) to WMV (windows)

Tags: video

I have been assigned a task that seems to be really hard for me.

I want to convert a video taken with iPhone4 (.mov) to a format that can be understood by Powerpoint (.wmv?)

I tried avidemux, but I don't know which is the correct format I must save the rotated file to.

I am using ubuntu 12.10

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_6296184_convert-_wmv-vlc-media-player.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily using `ffmpeg`.

If it is not already installed, install it using `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

To convert and rotate the file:

- clockwise by 90 degrees:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf transpose=1 output.wmv
  ```
- counter-clockwise by 90 degrees:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf transpose=2 output.wmv
  ```
- By 180 degrees:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf transpose=1,transpose=1 output.wmv
  ```

There are plethora of other options to configure. You can look and tweak them according to your needs, some options to consider *closely* would be the following video and audio options:

```
-c:v wmv2 -q:v 4 -c:a wmav2 -b:a 128k
```

This will give quite reasonable video quality with reasonable audio quality in a relatively small file size...